# Reading structure buffer from C++ Socket Server from Python Socket Client

Tags: python, c++, sockets

I need to read the structure buffer in python socket client that is sending from C++ server implementation. Not able to print proper values of uinit32_t and unit64_t.

I'm having structures from C++ server as mentioned below:

```
typedef struct TestData {
    uint8_t  id;
    uint8_t  location;
    uint64_t status;
} TestData_t;

typedef struct SendData {
    uint8_t  items;
    uint8_t  package_type;
    uint8_t  location;
    uint32_t length;
    uint8_t  v1;
    uint8_t  v2;
    uint32_t package_count;
    uint64_t timestamp;
    uint8_t  status;
    uint8_t  fail_reason;
    uint8_t  object_count;
    uint8_t  test_count;
    TestData_t  test_data[4];

} SendData_t;
```

Here is sending code from server:

```
udpsock.send_to(send_data_st, sizeof(struct SendData), srcAddr);
```

Reading from python client:

```
bufferSize          = 1028
msgFromServer = UDPClientSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
print(msgFromServer[0])

result = str(msgFromServer[0][0]) + ", " + str(msgFromServer[0][1]) + ", " + str(msgFromServer[0][2]) + ", " + str(msgFromServer[0][3]) + ", " + str(msgFromServer[0][4]) + ", " + str(msgFromServer[0][5]) + ", " + str(msgFromServer[0][6]) + ", " + str(msgFromServer[0][7])
        
print(result)
```

Not print the proper structure values of unit32, uint64.

This is my first post. Please guide me to get the results in python

Comment: Why are you using `typedef struct ...`? In any case, as a new user here, read [ask] and take the [tour]. You're also expected to extract a [mcve] and provide that here, including both expected and actual output. That said, take a look at the ctypes module, which is aimed at C (and C++) interaction.

Comment: Thanks for the response. @UlrichEckhardt, Here I have provided the C++ structure details from server and how am I reading from python.

Comment: The point of the [mcve] requirement is that you don't provide more than necessary (Two structs or just one? Thirteen members or just one or two?) and don't leave out details (What are the rests of the programs, both C++ and Python?). I should be able to copy'n'paste the code to reproduce the issue. That said, consider parsing a file where you have complete control over the content, just to get rid of the dependency on network traffic. Or, you could hard-code a byte string in Python even.